# WPF: TextBox materialDesign - how to Alignment HintAssist.Hint

Tags: wpf, textbox, material-design

So I have this `TexBox`:

```
<TextBox Height="30"
         BorderThickness="0"
         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasFilledTextField="False"
         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasOutlinedTextField="False"
         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden"
         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="Transparent"
         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.TextBoxViewMargin="10,3,0,0"
         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Search"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.HelperTextFontSize="12"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="False"/>
```

And I want to place my Hint (Search in my example) at the center of my `TexBox`.

Al i can found is to change `TextFieldAssist.TextBoxViewMargin` but of course this effect the input `text` as well.

Comment: What is the question you want to ask? No questions appear in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this code to textbox:

```
<TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:SmartHint}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
</TextBox.Resources>
```

Example

```
<TextBox Height="30"
     BorderThickness="0"
     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasFilledTextField="False"
     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasOutlinedTextField="False"
     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden"
     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="Transparent"
     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.TextBoxViewMargin="10,3,0,0"
     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True"
     materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Search"
     materialDesign:HintAssist.HelperTextFontSize="12"
     materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="False">
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:SmartHint}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Resources>
     
    </TextBox>
```